# Python on IIS on WinSrv2019

Tags: python, iis

I'm new, wanting to run python applications using IIS. What am I doing wrong ?

Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in mainenv
handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)File "C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" line 633
in read_wsgi_handlerhandler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
File "C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 586, in get_wsgi_handlerraise Exception('WSGI_HANDLER env var must be set') Exception: WSGI_HANDLER env var must be set StdOut: StdErr:
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You got wrong from WSGI. Microsoft only supports HttpPlatformHandler now, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info

Comment: This link should help you [Configure the FastCGI handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022#configure-the-fastcgi-handler), and microsoft recommend using HttpPlatform to configure your apps, as the WFastCGI project is no longer maintained.